# Как вызвать иконку загрузки в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

У меня сайт на ajax, при переходе по страницам надо бы вызывать индекацию, говорящую о загрузке. 
Просто всплывающие окошко на сайте вызывает какое-то отторжение, тогда я и подумал, что можно подменять фавикон, а можно пойти дальше и показывать родную анимацию в фавиконе от браузера.

Такую фичу я заметил ВК, но вот только они не меняют фавикон, как сделать так же? Как при ajax запросе заставить браузер думать, что страница загружается? Что бы он сам выводил родную индекацию или прогресс-бар загрузки

Comment: Проверил: ВКонтакте меняет иконку – браузер по-другому рисует «настоящую» загрузку страницы (*Firefox 41.0.1, OS X 10.11*) Сравните: http://i.imgur.com/ZbLI4Ji.png – сверху «родной», снизу ВК.

Comment: Серая иконка рисуется при переходе страницы, синяя - при загрузки контента страницы. Если скорость интернета большая - серую иконку можно не заметить. Они меняются: http://imgur.com/a/2FXUw (не обращайте внимание на фон, он меняется у меня каждые несколько секунд)

Comment: И инспектор не показал чтобы иконка ВК менялась

Comment: Вот есть схожий вопрос на EN SO - [How does Facebook show browser loading progress during AJAX Page Loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915772/how-does-facebook-show-browser-loading-progress-during-ajax-page-loads), говорят что это делается с помощью iframe. Якобы когда iframe вставляется на страницу, все что грузится внутри него, заставляет браузер показывать, что он что-то грузит. У Фейсбука все компоненты независимы стилями и js и грузятся через отдельные фреймы. К сожалению проверить это пока не получилось.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('link[rel$=icon]').remove();
$('head').append( $('<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>' ).attr( 'href', "/newicon.png" ) );
```

Добавляете код на ajax beforeLoad, и меняете обратно иконку при ajax success

Comment: Нет, нет. Я как раз такой вариант и отбросил, нужно именно заставлять браузер думать, что страница грузится.

Comment: В яндекс браузере, например, вообще адресная строка превращается в прогресс-бар

Comment: @Fanrin зачем же вам аякс если вы все равно хотите заставлять браузер думать что страница грузится как обычно?)
https://github.com/ejci/favico.js  тут посмотрите. Неплохая библиотека, позволяет в фавикон ставить видео, и даже из web-камеры передавать туда изображение)

Comment: Знаю библиотеку) А затем он, чтоб юзабилити было больше, пользователей напрягает что-то "не стандартное", да даже меня напрягает ajax твитера, когда загрузка появляется в шапке. Юзеру надо давать то, к чему он привык, и знать ему не надо, что на сайте какой-то там ajax

Answer (score 3):

Нужно создать `iframe`, у [его св-ва](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) `contentDocument` (которое возвращает объект `document` этого iframe) вызывать метод `open()`, чтобы браузер начал показывать процесс загрузки, и `close()` для прекращения.

Рабочий только в Firefox [пример с кнопкой](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/0p8L463y/)

```
var iframe = $('<iframe />', {
    name: 'loading',
    id:   'loading',
    width:  '1px',
    height: '1px',
    style: "display:none;"
}).appendTo('body');

var state = false;
$('#btn-trigger').on('click', function(){
    if( state) {
        iframe[0].contentDocument.close();
    } else {
        iframe[0].contentDocument.open();
    }
    state = !state;
});
```

Comment: Яндекс-браузер - не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, в Safari, Chrome и Opere тоже не работает. Когда писал, проверял только в Firefox.

Comment: Почти то, что нужно. Есть идеи, как реализовать хотя бы в хроме? Просто почти все пользователи им пользуются